# Инструкция для изучения анимаций

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Всем привет! Хотел бы спросить, что нужно знать и где это можно посмотреть, чтобы сделать анимацию вот такого вида?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При скролле до этого блока, должен сначала появляться блок с текстом, потом кружочек и от него идти линия до следующего блока.
Сама линия и круги вставлены общей svg.
Вот хочу узнать, за сколько времени и что нужно уметь чтобы сделать такое.
Делать пробовал, но ничего толком не вышло. Animate.css и AOS такого не подразумевают.

Comment: Посмотрите ScrollTrigger от gsap, он позволяет сделать такое. В [документации](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger) у них есть куча ссылок с примерами. [Вот](https://codepen.io/michellebarker/details/dyMQYYz) например

Comment: или [вот](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/details/mdWPMwY) отличный пример, почти как вам нужно

Comment: цитата: **Сама линия и круги вставлены общей svg.**  Желательно  добавить код svg в вопрос Отвечающим облегчите задачу, не нужно будет рисовать с нуля

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а я не добавил, чтобы за меня не делали))

Comment: @Greg--, благодарю, очень полезно

Answer (score 4):

Пример для старта изучения, как рисуются линии, кружки. Взаимодействие и последовательность анимаций

Ссылка на [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/955249/28748)

```css
.shape svg {
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
#outline1, #outline2 {
  fill:none;
 
 stroke-dasharray: 1192;
  animation: dash 17s linear forwards;
  stroke-linejoin: round; 
  stroke-width:4;
  
} 



@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1192;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
.container {

width:100%;
height:100%;
background: linear-gradient(to right,#B452A0, #895FDD );
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="90%" height="90%" viewBox="0 0 1214 863" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

<defs>


</defs>

 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ5NF.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>
    <path id="outline1" stroke="#EC1E4E" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3-38.2 48.5-58.5 12.5-16.7 19.9-37.4 34.7-52.1 13.4-13.3 29.7-24.9 47.5-31.1 16.2-5.6 34.2-7.1 51.2-4.6 18.5 2.7 35.8 11.8 52.1 21 23.5 13.2 43.4 30.3 64.9 48.5 17.3 14.6 39.6 25.5 62.2 27.4 21.3 1.8 41.6-9.9 62.2-15.5 20.5-5.6 40.4-13.7 61.3-18.3 18.6-4.1 37.6-8.4 56.7-8.2 19.4 0.1 39.4 2.3 57.6 9.1 20.5 7.7 36.1 25.1 55.8 34.7 21 10.4 42.4 23.1 65.8 24.7 21.8 1.5 44.6-4.5 64-14.6 19.9-10.4 38.4-16.2 58.5-21 18.8-4.5 38.2-7.4 57.6-7.3 20.9 0.1 41.8 3.6 62.2 8.2 19.1 4.3 36.9 13 55.8 18.3 15.4 4.3 46.6 11 46.6 11v0M62.2 447"/>
  <path id="outline2" stroke="#8B0FC5" d="m62.2 447c0 0 33.3 38.2 48.5 58.5 12.5 16.7 19.9 37.4 34.7 52.1 13.4 13.3 29.7 24.9 47.5 31.1 16.2 5.6 34.2 7.1 51.2 4.6 18.5-2.7 35.8-11.8 52.1-21 23.5-13.2 43.4-30.3 64.9-48.5 17.3-14.6 39.6-25.5 62.2-27.4 21.3-1.8 41.6 9.9 62.2 15.5 20.5 5.6 40.4 13.7 61.3 18.3 18.6 4.1 37.6 8.4 56.7 8.2 19.4-0.1 39.4-2.3 57.6-9.1 20.5-7.7 36.1-25.1 55.8-34.7 21-10.4 42.4-23.1 65.8-24.7 21.8-1.5 44.6 4.5 64 14.6 19.9 10.4 38.4 16.2 58.5 21 18.8 4.5 38.2 7.4 57.6 7.3 20.9-0.1 41.8-3.6 62.2-8.2 19.1-4.3 36.9-13 55.8-18.3 15.4-4.3 46.6-11 46.6-11v0" />
    <!-- Upper Running Triangle -->
  <polyline transform="translate(7 -12.5) rotate(90)" points="0,0 12.5,21.6 25,0" fill="#B51092" >
     <animateMotion
       id="an1_triangle"
       dur="17s"
       repeatCount="1"
       rotate="auto-reverse"
       begin="0s"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive">
           <mpath xlink:href="#outline1"/>
    </animateMotion>  
    <!-- Lower Running Triangle -->
</polyline>  
    <polyline transform="translate(7 -12.5) rotate(90)" points="0,0 12.5,21.6 25,0" fill="#6326DD" >
     <animateMotion
       id="an2_triangle"
       dur="17s"
       repeatCount="1"
       rotate="auto-reverse"
       begin="0s"
       fill="freeze"
       restart="whenNotActive">
           <mpath xlink:href="#outline2"/>
      </animateMotion>  
    </polyline>   
       <!-- Loader 1st Section -->
    <g transform="translate(30 265)">
        <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#EC1E4E" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc1"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="0s"
              repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc1"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc1.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     <!-- Animation checkbox 1st section -->  
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check1"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc1.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>   
           <!-- Loader 2nd Section -->
    <g transform="translate(330 265)">
        <circle id="crc2" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#CA0C52" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc2"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="an_check1.end-0.5s"
             repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc2"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc2.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     <!-- Animation checkbox 2nd section -->  
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check2"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc2.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>      
    
               <!-- Loader 3rd Section -->
    <g transform="translate(530 265)">
        <circle id="crc3" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#B51092" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc3"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="an_check2.end-0.5s"
             repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc3"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc3.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     <!-- Animation of the 3rd section checkbox -->  
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check3"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc3.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>  
       
               <!-- Loader 4th section -->
    <g transform="translate(730 265)">
        <circle id="crc4" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#8B0FC5" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc4"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="an_check3.end-0.5s"
             repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc4"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc4.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     <!-- Animation checkbox 4th section -->  
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check4"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc4.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>    
    
                   <!-- Loader 5th section -->
    <g transform="translate(930 265)">
        <circle id="crc5" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#6326DD" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc5"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="an_check4.end-0.5s"
             repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc5"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc5.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     <!-- Animation of the 5th section checkbox -->  
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check5"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc5.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>    
    
                       
    <g transform="translate(1085 265)">
        <circle id="crc6" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" fill="none" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#0336E1" stroke-width="3" 
            stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
        
          <animate id="an_crc6"
             attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
             values="33.88;0"
             dur="0.2s"
             begin="an_check5.end-0.5s"
             repeatCount="12"
             restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                 <animate id="fill_crc6"  attributeName="stroke-opacity" dur="1s" begin="an_crc6.end-0.5s" values="1;0" fill="freeze" />     
        </circle>    
                     
            <text x="15" y="43" fill="#00AF00" font-size="54" fill-opacity="0">&#10004;
             <animate id="an_check6"
                attributeName="fill-opacity"
                dur="1s"
                begin="fill_crc6.end-0.25s"
                values="0;1"
                fill="freeze" /> 
            </text>
    </g>  
       
    
     
  </svg> 
  </div>
```

Более [подробно здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1253), как делается анимация с помощью `stroke-dasharray` `stroke-dashoffset`

Можно по изучать [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1071694/28748) по прокладке и анимации маршрута на карте (в вашем случае на картинке)

```css
.container {
 width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
svg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
 
} 

.road{
  fill:none;
  stroke:blue;
  stroke-dasharray:12 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:3;
}
#steps{
   fill:none;
   stroke:white;
  stroke-dasharray:12 10;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;
  stroke-width:3;
   
}

#stepMask{
   fill:none;
   stroke:black;
   stroke-width:3;
   stroke-dashoffset: 1887;
   stroke-dasharray:1887,1887;
 
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   viewBox="0 0 1200 890" >
  
    <defs>
       <mask id="msk1">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
         <path id="stepMask"  d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" >
           <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0s" dur="40s" values="1887;0" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/> 
          </path> 
       </mask> 
        <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0s"
          dur="0.4s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
      </g> 
    </defs> 
     <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmr13.jpg"
     width="100%" height="100%" />
  <g id="Layer_1">
   
   <path class="road" d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" />
   <path id="steps" mask="url(#msk1)" d="m398.8 299.8c0 0 70.7-30.6 108.4-33.9 44.2-3.9 88.7 7.5 132 17 73.3 16 144.1 42.3 215 66.9 22.3 7.8 45.8 13.2 66 25.5 14.7 8.9 32.8 17.8 38.7 33.9 5.1 14-6.6 29.4-6.6 44.3 0.1 76 68.8 157.8 33.9 225.3-25.2 48.8-97.9 50-147.1 74.5-32.6 16.2-62.8 38.9-98.1 48.1-34.1 8.9-70.4 6.9-105.6 5.7-72.5-2.5-163.4 23.6-215.9-26.4-31.9-30.3-9.5-88.1-22.6-130.1-8-25.8-9.6-61.8-33.9-73.5-54.1-26.2-175.4 42.4-175.4 42.4" />
   
  
  </g>  
  
    <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(2.5)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="0s"
       dur="40s"
       repeatCount="1"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#steps"/>
     </animateMotion>    

    </use>  
</svg>
</div>
```

Довольно подробно объяснены основные моменты

Comment: Благодарю, буду пробовать